# line numbers in event viewer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, event-log

I'm getting an exception in a windows service I'm working on. It isn't being caught by any of my try/catch blocks (which I have everywhere) but I can see it in the Windows Event Log.  Is there a way to make the exception in the Event Log include line numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event and you will not miss unhandled exception:

```
public static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

    // Service Run
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // log exception e.ExceptionObject
}
```

Comment: @Joshua Evensen - to see code line numbers you need to have pdb file deployed along with exe file. If you don't have pdb file, there is no way to correlate IL code to source code lines.

Comment: @Joshua Evensen - did you solve your problem? did you try adding pdb files?

Comment: @AlexAza - I'm facing a similar problem to Joshua, but when I have the .pdb files in the same directory as their executable counterparts, no line numbers are output in the event viewer. Any ideas? (This is on Windows Server 2008 R2)